# Regex look past character

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match fx. this string

"dfsdfsdf 100.200,00"

This is what i got

```
[0-9\.]+
```

That returns

```
100.200
```

Is there anyway WITH REGEX i can just look paste the dot. So i will get:

```
100200
```

Comment: You must use `MATCH` and `REPLACE`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$str = 'dfsdfsdf 100.200,00';
preg_match('/(\d+)\.(\d+)/', $str, $m);
$res = $m[1] . $m[2];
echo $res,"\n";
```

**outout:**

```
100200
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
preg_replace("/^.*?(\d+)\.(\d+).*?$/", '$1$2', "dfsdfsdf 100.200,00");
```

it will replace the whole string with the matched digits

working example in [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/tx8-uck)